# Correcting the large datasets using AWK?

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a large data set with 3 columns. The columns not align correctly at some places, e.g.,

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
9-1  -2
1-3  -5
1 -12 -43
1 -14 -09
```

How can I correct or create the space between the columns so that I can read them?

Desired output:

```
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
9 -1  -2
1 -3  -5
1 -12 -43
1 -14 -09
```

Comment: Why did you specify AWK in the title but then tag with [tag:python] and [tag:bash] and accept a Bash/Python solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of `sed` will add a space before every `-` not preceded by a space:

```
sed 's/\([^[:blank:]]\)-/\1 -/g' fname
```

This takes all expressions not starting with a `blank` and followed by a `-` to replace with space and `-`.

In python:

```
import re

with open('fname','r') as f:
    data = re.sub(r'([0-9])(-)',r'\1'+' '+r'\2',f.read())
```

Here we use `re.sub()` with group capture and replace with both groups with a space inserted in the middle.

Comment: Thanks! Could you please explain a bit what this line do?

Answer (score 1):

You want columns? There's a tool for that with a fairly obvious name...

```
$ sed 's/-/ -/g' file | column -t
0  1    2
3  4    5
6  7    8
9  -1   -2
1  -3   -5
1  -12  -43
1  -14  -09
```

or:

```
$ sed 's/-/ -/g' file | column -tR1,2,3
0    1    2
3    4    5
6    7    8
9   -1   -2
1   -3   -5
1  -12  -43
1  -14  -09
```

Answer (score 0):

- `I don't want to create space between all data, only with few which looks like 4 and 5 row`.

Using `awk` with `sub()` function:

```
awk '$1 ~ /-/ {sub(/-/, " &")} 1' file
0  1  2
3  4  5
6  7  8
9 -1  -2
1 -3  -5
1 -12 -43
1 -14 -09
```